# Passing a column into a where in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have a table `event_log` and a table `apps`

Here are a few rows from the table `event-log`

```
select * from event_log;
Date     | Appname | User | Message
01-09-15 | mail    | u1   | logged in
01-09-15 | ssh     | u2   | test
01-09-15 | grep    | u1   | temp
01-09-15 | mail    | u6   | test temp
01-09-15 | putty   | u8   | logged in
01-09-15 | mail    | u1   | logged out
```

Here are a few rows from the table `apps`

```
select * from apps;
AppName  | Message 
mail     | email
ssh      | remote connection
grep     | search
putty    | external app
temp     | testing app
```

Now I was want to search all the rows from `event_log` for each AppName from `apps`

That is for each AppName in apps select from event_log.

I tried

```
SELECT EL.DATE, EL.APPNAME FROM  EVENT_LOG EL
WHERE EL.APPNAME = (SELECT APP.APPNAME FROM APPS APP);
```

But I get the following error :

```
"single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Comment: Your immediate problem would be solved by replacing the `=` in your `WHERE` clause with an `IN` operator. Does that get you what you want?

Comment: @Politank-Z how would I get the total number of rows returned here

Comment: your question is ambiguous. Total number of rows from where?